# Loop inside a FOR loop

Tags: database, postgresql, loops, for-loop, plpgsql

I'd like to set up a query with a loop inside a for loop.
I'm writing it like :

```sql
FOR ___ IN value..value BY 1 LOOP
  LOOP
    statement
    EXIT WHEN ...
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

It returns me a syntax error around the second "loop", that's why I doubt the feasibility of such a loop inside a for loop.

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=684923418e5619ef15a7bf1656b6ab62 It seem that you have the error is not related to the `loop` statement itself. Post the full error text.

Comment: Offtopic: Are you sure you need a loop? Relational databases work on sets and in my experience all loops can be replaced by a better (and faster!) solution. A double loop looks even worse...

Comment: *It returns me a syntax error* - What error? It's on the screen right in front of you. Unfortunately, we can't see that screen, so it's up to you to include that information in your question. The **complete, exact error message** helps us find a solution to your problem faster, which benefits you. As I said, it's on your screen already, so there's no excuse for failing to put it in your question.

Answer (score 4):

I see no problem to do a nested loop in `plgpgsql` in postgresql 11.10:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    i integer;
    j integer;
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..2 LOOP
    FOR j IN 10..12 LOOP
    -- i will take on the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 within the loop
    RAISE NOTICE 'loop % %',i,j;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END$$;
```

I see expected output:

```
loop 1 10
loop 1 11
loop 1 12
loop 2 10
loop 2 11
loop 2 12
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the initial problem I see is your counter is iterating on a range of "value..value"

Take a look at this code, the range should be 2 different values. Try this first.

```
do $$
begin 
  for counter in 1..6 by 2 loop
    raise notice 'counter: %', counter;
  end loop;
end; $$
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood how 2 loops could be substituted by one loop in such form as you wrote.

Comment: @AlexYu the issue is the values being iterated on, there is no range when your range is "1..1" or "value..value"

Answer (score 0):

The [LOOP statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS-LOOP) in a [FOR statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-INTEGER-FOR) below works. *I use PostgreSQL 16.1.

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  num INT := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR num IN 1..3 BY 1 LOOP
    LOOP
      EXIT WHEN num >= 3; -- Here
      RAISE INFO 'Inner loop:num is %.', num;
      num := num + 1;
    END LOOP;
    RAISE INFO 'Outer loop:num is %.', num;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

This is the output below:

```
INFO:  Inner loop:num is 1.
INFO:  Inner loop:num is 2.
INFO:  Outer loop:num is 3.
INFO:  Inner loop:num is 2.
INFO:  Outer loop:num is 3.
INFO:  Outer loop:num is 3.
DO
```